# E/Volley: [127] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for

Tags: android, post, android-volley

error :- E/Volley: [127] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for

how can i solve this error?

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_POST, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject msgjson = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.d("aaaaa", String.valueOf(msgjson));
                    Log.d("aaa", "aaa");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("aaa", "aaa");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String id = "524901";
                String units = "metric";
                String appid = "67aa03cd6bedc6f6fb6f9f506968f3d6";

                params.put("id", id);
                params.put("units", units);
                params.put("appid", appid);

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not code error. as per [w3](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).org

> 401 Unauthorized - The request requires user authentication.

So it may be error because you are unauthorized to access that api. Check session or key.